# Using Sublime Text on Windows and eslint on windows linux subsystem

Tags: windows, sublimetext3, eslint, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sublimelinter

I have node, npm and eslint instaled on WSL. 
Can't setup Sublimelinter in Sublime Text 3 in Windows to hook up with eslint installed via bash in WSL.
Which path's i should enter in linter settings in Sublime?

Answer (score -1):

Sublimetext3 works inside WSL so you can install the Sublimetext3 linux binaries and use an Xserver on Windows side to launch it. With that method, plugins that need things installed inside WSL should work.

https://medium.com/@pck/how-to-use-sublime-text-3-from-command-line-with-ubuntu-bash-terminal-in-windows-10-subsystems-for-aa2ad59d088c

Edit: If the plugin is simple enough you can call linux binaries from Windows Sublimetext3 (32bit) with the command

> bash.exe -c "bash command"

For example, you can try modifying ESLint.py with something like this

```
args = {
      'cmd': [
        'C:\\windows\\sysnative\\bash.exe',
        '-c',
        'node',
        linter_path,
        files[0],
        node_modules_path,
        config_file
      ],
```

But then you will see is not that simple. You will have problems with paths like c:\myfolder being /mnt/c/myfolder on WSL and so on.
At the end It's easier to just use the Ubuntu binaries.

Comment: Yes, i know about this trick, but is there a way to make work windows version of Sublime exactly?